# Camel File processing

Tags: java, configuration, routes, apache-camel, file-uri

I'm using Camel (2.11.0) to *try* and achieve the following functionality:

- If a file exists at a certain location, copy it to another location and then begin processing it
- If no such file exists, then I don't want the file consumer/poller to block; I just want processing to continue to a `direct:cleanup` route

**I only want the file to be polled once!**

Here's what I have so far (using Spring XML):

```
<camelContext id="my-camel-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="my-route
        <from uri="file:///home/myUser/myApp/fizz?include=buzz_.*txt"/>

        <choice>
            <when>
                <!-- If the body is empty/NULL, then there was no file. Send to cleanup route. -->
                <simple>${body} == null</simple>
                <to uri="direct:cleanup" />
            </when>

            <otherwise>
                <!-- Otherwise we have a file. Copy it to the parent directory, and then continue processing. -->
                <to uri="file:///home/myUser/myApp" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>

        <!-- We should only get here if a file existed and we've already copied it to the parent directory. -->
        <to uri="bean:shouldOnlyGetHereIfFileExists?method=doSomething" />
    </route>

    <!--
        Other routes defined down here, including one with a "direct:cleanup" endpoint.
    -->
</camelContext>
```

With the above configuration, if there is no file at `/home/myUser/myApp/fizz`, then Camel just waits/blocks until there is one. Instead, I want it to just give up and move on to `direct:cleanup`.

And if there is a file, I see it getting processed inside the `shouldOnlyGetHereIfFileExists` bean, but I do not see it getting copied to `/home/myUser/myApp`; so it's almost as if the `<otherwise>` element is being skipped/ignored altogether!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this setting, and tune your polling interval to suit:

From [Camel File Component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) docs:

> sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle
>
> default =false
>
> Camel 2.9: If the polling consumer did not poll any files, you can enable this option to send an empty message (no body) instead.

Regarding writing the file, add a log statement inside the `<otherwise>` to ensure it's being executed. If so, check file / folder permissions, etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @vikingsteve - I'd give you a +1 but I don't have enough rep. I feel badly, there's an important piece I forgot to mention: **I only want the route to poll for the file once.** Your suggestion for `sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle` does work, but the route continuously polls, over and over again for a file. Any ideas as to how I can configure Camel to only poll one time? Thanks again!

Comment: Well there is also a `delay` option - you could try setting that to 0, or -1, or some extremely large value, and see what happens. Otherwise, during the first execution of your route, you could use `controlbus` to stop the route.

Comment: Looks like delay cannot be <= 0, but you could try a really high value. Otherwise, throwing an Exception (which you handle somehow) might also stop the route.

Answer (score 0):

One error i faced while I tried using the condition:

```
 <simple>${body} != null</simple>
```

was it always returns true.

Please go through the below link:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/choice-when-check-BodyType-null-Body-null-td4259599.html

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but if anyone finds this, you can poll only once with
"?repeatCount=1"

Comment: it is part of the quartz component.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was done almost 4 years ago but I had exaclty the same problem yesterday.
So I will let my answer here, maybe it will help another person.
I am using Camel, version 3.10.0

To make it work exactly as described in the question:

- If a file exists at a certain location, copy it to another location and then begin processing it
- If no such file exists, then I don't want the file consumer/poller to block; I just want processing to continue to a direct:cleanup route
- ONLY want the file to be polled once!

Using ${body} == null
The configuration that we need are:

**sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true**   //Will send a empty body when Idle

**maxMessagesPerPoll=1**            //Max files that it will take at once

**repeatCount=1**                   //How many times will execute the Pool (above)

**greedy=true**                     // If the last pool executed with files, it will
execute one more time

XML:

```
<camel:endpoint id="" uri="file:DIRECTORY?sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;initialDelay=100&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;repeatCount=1&amp;greedy=false" />
```